# How would I mount a Docker volume to WSL2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I installed Docker for Windows and switched to using WSL 2 Linux containers (without having any Linux knowledge whatsoever).

When I run a container, mounting a Docker volume to a Windows folder, I get a warning message telling me that I should rather mount the Docker volume to the WSL 2 distribution.

How would I do that?

When I execute Docker in PowerShell, I don't seem to have access to the WSL 2 file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use a folder as a volume, you can point docker (under PowerShell) to the WSL filesystem using the `\\wsl$\<distroname>` pseudo-share.  E.g.:

```
docker run -ti --volume "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\var\docker\volumes\alpine_persistent_data:/data" --rm alpine
```

Given a distribution named "Ubuntu" (the most common default WSL install), that will create and use `\var\docker\volumes\alpine_persistent_data` as a volume.

That said, I'd recommend using Docker managed volumes rather than directories for this.  See the Docker [volumes doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  Something like:

```
# Optional , since the volume will be created on first use anyway
docker volume create alpine_persistent_data

docker run -ti --volume alpine_persistent_data:/data --rm alpine

# or
docker run -ti --mount source=alpine-persistent-data,target=/data --rm alpine

# Cleanup
docker volume rm alpine-persistent-data
```

With Docker Desktop for Windows, the volumes will be stored in the *docker-desktop-data* WSL instance that you see with the `wsl -l -v` command.  This is a "black box" WSL instance which cannot be launched; it is simply used by the Docker Desktop backend for storage of images and volumes (and likely other Docker artifacts).

You *can* inspect the contents of this WSL instance.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1613591/1210833) for details.

Comment: Very informative answer! I couldn't find anything near to this in the docs. Would you mind if I updated the Docker for Windows documentation with your information and create a PR from that?

Comment: Don't mind at all - Happy to contribute, and glad it helped you!

Comment: I still have a question, if you don't mind: In your `bind mount` example you suggest to bind to a WSL share (`--volume "\\wsl$\...`). What would be the reason for this? I would have guessed that binding to a local folder would be the way to go (e.g. `--volume "C:\Temp\:/data"`). What's the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Binding to something on the NTFS drive seemed to be your problem in the first place, in that Docker gave you a warning that performance would be impacted, right?  The ``\\wsl$\`` pseudo-share passed in a path in the WSL2 instance, where the ext4 filesystem there is much (more than an order of magnitude) faster than NTFS (see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ntfs%209p%20wsl) and [this result](https://vxlabs.com/2019/12/06/wsl2-io-measurements/)). Also, when passed a ``\\wsl$\`` share, WSL auto-maps it -- Try launching with ``wsl --cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\``, and WSL will start in its `/`.

Comment: I now created a documentation on mounting Volumes in Docker for Windows: https://deploy-preview-12877--docsdocker.netlify.app/docker-for-windows/mounts-on-windows/ and created a pull request: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/12877 . It needs a review though ...