# How to use WSL2 ubuntu filesystem in a Docker Compose Bind mount in Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I'm using Windows 10 with WSL 2 and Docker. I've a Docker Compose in the windows filesystem and I want to create a bind mount using my files hosted in the Ubuntu WSL2.

I've tried the bellow settings but no lucky. When I try to `docker compose up` the docker bugs, probably because the `wls$` sys variable.

```
volumes:
    app_files: 
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            o: bind            
            device: "//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/dev/app
```

Is it possible to set the docker-compose.yml to bind the content inside the WSL 2 distro? Someone knows how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Why not run the docker container inside WSL instead? There you have access to both the linux and the windows (`/mnt/c/` for example) files.

Comment: @Super The problem with it is that Docker Dashboard in windows breaks when try to stop/start  containers with volumes inside  the wsl. I use a lot of docker dash to manage the correct docker-compose in my dev env.

Comment: If you run a container in WSL is still shows up in your docker dashboard. Also docker-compose etc.

Comment: @super it does, but if you stop and try to start another one  via dashboard it will crash if the compose was set via wsl =/

Comment: Ok, I don't seem to have that issue. I can stop and start the container that was created in wsl without any issues.

Comment: Does Docker/Docker-Compose allow slashes to be used in place of backslashes?  That's a Windows path, so the slashes should be reversed, but I'm not sure that it matters.  Some multi-platform apps correct that for the user, some don't.  Also, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525916/11810933) where I had it working with `docker`, at least.  I'm guessing `docker-compose` should use the same syntax.